# Join of 2 dataframes

Tags: r, join

I have 2 dataframes and I want to join by name, but names are not written exactly the same:

```
Df1:

ID    Name       Age
1     Jose        13
2     M. Jose     12
3     Laura        8
4     Karol P     32

Df2:
Name         Surname
José           Hall
María José     Perez
Laura          Alza
Karol          Smith


I need to join and get this:

ID    Name       Age   Surname
1     Jose        13     Hall
2     M. Jose     12     Perez
3     Laura        8     Alza
4     Karol P     32     Smith
```

How to consider that the names are not exactly the same before to join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close to your result using `stringdist_left_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = "Name")

#  ID  Name.x Age Name.y Surname
#1  1    Jose  13   José    Hall
#2  2 M. Jose  12   <NA>    <NA>
#3  3   Laura   8  Laura    Alza
#4  4 Karol P  32  Karol   Smith
```

For the example shared it does not work for 1 entry since it is difficult to match `Maria` with `M.`. You can get the result for it by adjusting the `max_dist` argument to a higher value (default is 2) however, this will screw up other results and would give unwanted matches. If you have minimal `NA` entries (like the example shared) after this join you could just match them by "hand".

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 0):

I would clean the database before (for example deleting those ´, in excel is easy doing those replace) and then use

```
 new_df <- merge(df1, df2, by="name")
```

or you could try to assign an ID for df2 that coincide with df2 if it is possible.